# internal server error heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

im developing a application in ruby with sinatra. evrything worked finely until i put it on heroku. heroku gives me internal server error but no error code ):
currently my workstation is a windows computer.
my log loooks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAv2P.png
config.ru

```
require 'tilt/haml'
require 'sass/plugin/rack'
require '4c96748'
run Sinatra::Application
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.3'
gem 'sinatra', '1.1.0'
```

procfile

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

4c96748.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'tilt/haml'

get '/' do
    haml :index
end
```

pleaase help me, what do i need to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *Please* do not use an image to display logs (or code or data). We can't reuse that to search and instead have to type pertinent information in by hand, slowing answers and possibly causing errors. Copy it, reduce the information to the bare minimum necessary to let us know what's going on, and paste that text into the question, formatted appropriately. Links to off-site resources tend to rot and break, making them useless in the future.

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow isn't a discussion board or a stream of text messages. Please take the time to use correct grammar and punctuation. You're helping create a reference book. "im" -> "I'm", "ruby" -> "Ruby", "sinatra" -> "Sinatra", "evrything" -> "everything", etc. Grammar does count and pays off with more attention paid to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following in your 6c96748.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

get '/' do
  haml :index
end
```

Comment: and  gem "haml" in the gemfile

Answer (score 1):

From your logfile:

```
LoadError - cannot load such file -- haml
```

There is no Haml installed on Heroku. Every dependency you need on Heroku needs to be in your `Gemfile`.

Add the following Line to `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'haml'
```

Don't forget to run `bundle` before commiting your changes and pushing to heroku again.

(As a sidenote, your Sinatra version is quite outdated. The current version is `1.4.6` (see https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra))